# Drawing multiple RecyclerView ItemDecoration after getItemOffsets

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

Is it possible for an RecyclerView ItemDecoration to "know" the offsets specified by other individual ItemDecoration's in order to draw itself without overlapping the previous draw.

I know its possible to get the total offset with the LinearLayoutManager of the RecyclerView but this is not stored in a fashion that makes an individual offset determinable.

Comment: Most Android code will put you in trouble if you force it to not work as intended. I will try to avoid it if does not perfectly fit your needs.

Comment: I'm aware of best practices, I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place

Comment: Well, i usually use my own "best practices" where i can, thats why i recommend you to not use the Android classes if they dont fit your needs, sometimes it takes more time to write a shorter code than a longer code.

Comment: The issue isn't with shorter code, there was no alternative available to achieve the desired result, without going into detail this is now the issue I'm trying to tackle, can we please stay on topic.